# nginx is redirecting subdomain into parent domain

Tags: redirect, nginx, proxypass, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup GitLab in subdomain.mydomain.com. But when calling this url, it is getting redirected into www.mydomain.com. Following is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/subdomain.mydomain.com file. I followed this [link](https://www.linode.com/docs/development/version-control/how-to-unbundle-nginx-from-omnibus-gitlab-for-serving-multiple-websites).

```
upstream gitlab {
            server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.mydomain.com;
    server_tokens off; 
    root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

    client_max_body_size 250m;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://gitlab;
    }
}
```

What's wrong in this configuration.

Comment: Check you configuration using `nginx -T` to ensure that you have the files in the correct place.

Comment: There are no configuration errors showing up when executing this command.